# MVC4 Cascading dropdown list just working for 2 dropdown lists and not for more than that

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I am using MVC4/EF and I have three cascading dropdownlist and fourth a listbox which loads records based on 3rd dropdownlist. I wana select the first dropdown and filter the result on the second, and by selecting second dropdowm the third dropdwon is filtered, based on the 3rd drop down I populate a list box. Its working just for the 2nd dropdownlist which loads records based on 1st one.  But when change the selection in the 2nd drop down, it is filtering the 3rddrop down i.e. when i change the selection in the 2nd drop down it is not resetting the third, Actually `$("#ddlUsers").change(function () { });` is not called when i change selection of 2nd drop down. here is my code

My Create View has these major elements

First dropdown

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", (SelectList)ViewData["Departments"], "--Select Department--", new { Id = "ddlDepartments" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
    </div>
```

2nd dropdown

```
<div id="dvUser" class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("UserId", new SelectList(new[] { "--Select Manager--" }), new { Id = "ddlUsers" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
    </div>
```

3rd dropdown

```
<div id="dvLead" class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("UserId", new SelectList(new[] { "--Select Lead--" }), new { Id = "ddlLead" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LeadID)
    </div>
```

Now a list box

```
div id="dvEmployees" class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBox("Employees", new MultiSelectList(new[] { "--Select Item--" }), new { id = "sourceItems", Multiple = "multiple" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentEmployees)
    </div>
```

My JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {

    registerPageEvents('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Create"))', '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Edit", new { id = "__ID__" }))', 'ID');

    $("#ddlDepartments").change(function () {
        debugger;
        var postParams = { deptId: $("#ddlDepartments").val() };
        $.post('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("LoadManagerCombo", "DepartmentManager", new { area = "Administration", Controller = "DepartmentManager" }))' + '/', postParams)
        .done(function (newRow) {
            $("#dvUser").html(newRow);
        })
        .fail(function (ex1, ex2, ex3) {
            alert("error occured while Loading Manager");
        });

    });


    $("#ddlUsers").change(function () {
        debugger;
        var postParams = { deptId: $("#ddlDepartments").val(), managerId: $("#ddlUsers").val() };
        $.post('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("LoadUserOtherThanMangerCombo", "DepartmentManager", new { area = "Administration", Controller = "DepartmentManager" }))' + '/', postParams)
        .done(function (newRow) {
            $("#dvLead").html(newRow);
        })
        .fail(function (ex1, ex2, ex3) {
            alert("error occured while Loading Lead");
        });

    });

    $("#ddlLead").change(function () {
        debugger;
        var postParams = { deptId: $("#ddlDepartments").val(), managerId: $("#ddlUsers").val(), leadId: $("#ddlLead").val() };
        $.post('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("LoadEmployeeListBox", "DepartmentManager", new { area = "Administration", Controller = "DepartmentManager" }))' + '/', postParams)
        .done(function (newRow) {
            $("#dvEmployees").html(newRow);
        })
        .fail(function (ex1, ex2, ex3) {
            alert("error occured while Loading Employees");
        });

    });


});
```

I have made different partial Views for 2nd, and third dropdown and fourth(the list box)

For 2nd one

```
@model CubicHRM.Data.Entities.Employee

@Html.DropDownList("UserId", (SelectList)ViewData["Manager"], "--Select Manager/Head--", new { Id = "ddlUsers" })
```

with controller function

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadManagerCombo(int deptId)
    {
        List<int> ManagerIds = db.DepartmentManagerRepository.Get().Select(u => u.UserID).ToList();
        List<int> LeadIds = db.DepartmentManagerRepository.Get().Select(u => u.LeadID).ToList();
        ViewData["Manager"] = new SelectList(db.UsersRepository.Get().Where(u => u.DepartmentID == deptId && !ManagerIds.Contains(u.UserId) && !LeadIds.Contains(u.UserId)).ToList(), "UserId", "UserName");
        return PartialView();
    }
```

for 3rd one

```
@model CubicHRM.Data.Entities.Employee

@Html.DropDownList("UserId", (SelectList)ViewData["Lead"], "--Select Lead--", new { Id = "ddlLead" })
```

with action method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadUserOtherThanMangerCombo(int deptId, int managerId)
    {
        List<int> ManagerIds = db.DepartmentManagerRepository.Get().Select(u => u.UserID).ToList();
        List<int> LeadIds = db.DepartmentManagerRepository.Get().Select(u => u.LeadID).ToList();
        ViewData["Lead"] = new SelectList(db.UsersRepository.Get().Where(u => u.UserId != managerId && u.DepartmentID == deptId && !ManagerIds.Contains(u.UserId) && !LeadIds.Contains(u.UserId)).ToList(), "UserId", "UserName");
        return PartialView();
    }
```

and now for list box

```
@model CubicHRM.Data.Entities.Employee
@Html.ListBox("Employees", new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<CubicHRM.Data.Entities.Employee>)(ViewData["Employees"]), "UserID", "UserName"), new { id = "sourceItems", Multiple = "multiple" })
```

with action mehod

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadEmployeeListBox(int deptId, int managerId, int leadId)
    {
        List<int> ManagerIds = db.DepartmentManagerRepository.Get().Select(u => u.UserID).ToList();
        List<int> LeadIds = db.DepartmentManagerRepository.Get().Select(u => u.LeadID).ToList();
        ViewData["Employees"] = new SelectList(db.UsersRepository.Get().Where(u => u.UserId != managerId && u.DepartmentID == deptId && u.UserId != leadId && !ManagerIds.Contains(u.UserId) && !LeadIds.Contains(u.UserId)).ToList(), "UserId", "UserName");
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Can some one plz tell that why i am not able to load records in 3rd dropdown and fourth (the list box). When i debug its even doesn't call

```
$("#ddlUsers").change(function () {
        debugger;
        var postParams = { deptId: $("#ddlDepartments").val(), managerId: $("#ddlUsers").val() };
        $.post('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("LoadUserOtherThanMangerCombo", "DepartmentManager", new { area = "Administration", Controller = "DepartmentManager" }))' + '/', postParams)
        .done(function (newRow) {
            $("#dvLead").html(newRow);
        })
        .fail(function (ex1, ex2, ex3) {
            alert("error occured while Loading Lead");
        });

    });
```

and i don't know why? Can any one help me in this matter?

**Update**

I just moved the     `$("#ddlUsers").change(function () { });`      code in the partial view created for loading     `'ddlUsers'`  dropdown and now i am able to load         `'ddlLead'`  dropdown. but again this fails when i click on 3rd dropdown i.e. `ddllead`.  Function      `$("#ddlLead").change(function () { });`     is not being called, what can be the matter? Why a post back trick works for just one control?

Comment: I just moved the      $("#ddlUsers").change(function () { });       code in the partial view created for loading     'ddlUsers'  dropdown and now i am able to load         'ddlLead'  dropdown. but again this fails when i click on 3rd dropdown i.e. ddllead.  Function       $("#ddlLead").change(function () { });     is not being called, what can be the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved the two onchange functions (other than firstone) to other views, which load my dropdowns. Actually it was a post back issue, so on single view Change for more than one "ddl" was not fired. Moving it to Partial Views did the trick